# Started new role, but want to apply for an internal position

Tags: internal-transfer

I'm a new employee in an organization, and have just started in role for which I am overqualified for. I am not learning any new skills and don't feel stretched at all. The pay is awful too, although I love the company, manager, and colleagues.

My line manager knows that I am over qualified and is already telling me that I should be aware that the company likes to advertise internally, although I shouldn't try anything right now, as I have only started a month ago.

But the thing is there is something that has come up that I'd love to apply for. I am at least going to inquire about the position with the recruitment manager.

There is no internal recruitment policy at work, but I don't want to seem unethical or unreasonable.

Comment: i forgot to say... i only started a month ago!

Comment: If your manager is hinting that you should apply, there's little reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

The company has spent money advertising the position you applied for. They spent even more money having HR personnel go through resume's, schedule interviews, etc. Then decision makers had to take time out of their busy schedules to interview candidates, etc.

Now, not even a month later, you want to jump to a new position, causing the original department/team that went through all that trouble to do so again.

In most organizations you would be seen as unreliable. Additionally, you have probably not yet passed probation, which makes it an even greater risk to promote you.

You could, and maybe even should, express an interest to your line manager, but shy away from saying that you are dissatisfied with your current job. Complaining about compensation, challenge, etc. when you're new on the job is a good way to become unemployed.

My personal opinion is that you shouldn't try to make a move until you're 6 months to a year in, and you've developed a reputation within the organization.